# Angular 6 default value of select is not getting selected in Reactive Form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form which is shown below. And having a zone  drop down with default value  is "ALL" and other values are populated from an api call.

```
 <form method="POST" for enctype="multipart/form-data" [formGroup]="unitSearchForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Zone">Zone</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="zone" formControlName="zoneId">
                <option [ngValue]="0">All</option>
                <option [ngValue]="zone.ZoneId" *ngFor="let zone of (_zones|async)?.Result">{{ zone.ZoneName}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" id="search" formControlName="unitName"
                placeholder="Search by Unit Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control" formControlName="status">
                <option [ngValue]="status.Code" *ngFor="let status of _statusArr">{{status.Name}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="align-self-end form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary" (click)="SearchUnits()"><i
                  class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>Search</button>
            </div>
          </form>

/*
Component Code
*/

      ngOnInit() {
        this.InitilizeSearchForm();
        this.InitilizeSelectors();
      }


      private InitilizeSearchForm() {
        this.unitSearchForm = this._fb.group({
          zoneId: ['0'],
          unitName:['',Validators.maxLength(100)],
          status:['A']
        });
      }

      private InitilizeSelectors(){
        let searchCriteria: IDictionary = {}
        this._statusArr=this._dataservice.GetStatus();
        this._zones = this._adminService.Getzones(searchCriteria);
        searchCriteria["status"] =  this.unitSaveForm.get('status').value;
      }
```

How do i select the "All" in the zone drop down? I tried to set the value  when I  was  initialising the form. But it is not working.  Always the first selected value is  nothing.

Comment: `[ngValue]="value"` means the option's value will actually be `value`, instead of that value converted to a string. This is very useful Behavior but it means that your initial value in the form needs to be the number `0` not the string `'0'` because `'0' !== 0`

Comment: @Vipin do any of zone elements have ZoneId =  'All' ? Or do you need to add it dynamically?

Comment: @vadi, I already have in html option "All". I don't want this to be added as part of the rxjs request. When I select in form field default value=0 assigned. You can see InitilizeSearchForm method atttached in my question. So I have selected zoneId as zero. but it is not selecting the All option in the drop down.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad I tried you suggestion , When i intialise form in InitilizeSearchForm . Tried to set zoneid:0 . But it is not selecting "All"

Comment: I'm surprised, that ought to work. Perhaps it's a timing issue. I'm only speculating, but I don't see why you delay creating the form

Comment: @Aluan Haddad Below solution is working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[value]` binding for options and `[selected]` binding for `All` option:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Zone">Zone</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="zone" formControlName="zoneId">
    <option value="All" [selected]="'All'">All</option>
    <option [value]="zone.ZoneId" *ngFor="let zone of (_zones|async)?.Result">{{ zone.ZoneName}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-fill-form-input-stackoverflow-jgvvhk)

Comment: What is the different between ngValue and value

Comment: @Vipin `value` for string, `ngValue` can be used for objects. Both work in this case.

Comment: Yes it is working for me if i use ngvalue or value. I am bit confused now. Do i need to pass in selected property value in single quote

Comment: Ok i got it . Selected is property binding. So If i don't use single quote. It will look for a variable all. Thanks

Comment: @Vipin I've specified it in single quote inside of double quote because [selected]="All" without single quote means that you have somewhere in your component a variable with the name All. You can also make it in this way: in component: defaultOpts = 'All', then in template [selected]="defaultOpts"